# Save audit_trial in SYS.AUD$

Tags: oracle

I am trying to save audit trial in oracle at sys.AUD$ table but it shows error
my command prompt code is

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trial=db SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

It works perfect in other computer bt it shows error as 
ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM

Answer (score 0):

See [audit_trial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams016.htm#REFRN10006). You can use audit instead as `audit select table by FRED by access;`

> You can use the SQL statement AUDIT to set auditing options regardless
>   of the setting of this parameter.